# Update a id from data in json, with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json file from my cart. Now when my cart updates the file output correctly.

The json in order to be able to call out values from it to update field on the website.

here is a list of some variables from the json file:

```
"items":                <cms:pp_count_items/>,
"unique_items":         <cms:pp_count_unique_items/>,
"shippable_items":      <cms:pp_count_shippable_items/>,
"sub_total":            <cms:pp_sub_total/>,
"discount":             <cms:pp_discount/>,
"sub_total_discounted": <cms:pp_sub_total_discounted/>,
"taxes":                <cms:pp_taxes/>,
"shipping":             <cms:pp_shipping/>,
"total":                <cms:pp_total/>,
```

in the html file i have a field like this:

```
<span id="cart_total"><cms:number_format "<cms:pp_total />" /></span>
```

I have tried writing the following script to update "pp_total" one once this is clicked:

```
<div class="button_red" id="update-total"> Update total </div>
```

The script:

```
 $('#update-total').click(function (e) {
 $('#cart_total') callback();
$('#total').html+('#cat_total);

 });
```

So when id="update-total" is clicked, data from json "total" is extracted and put into id="cart_total".

Do i need to include the json file directory for it to call from? i cant get the script to work?

Comment: What's your precise question?

Comment: You forget the question...

Comment: sorry. I cant figure out the script to call it and implement it.

Comment: do i need to call the json file in jquery too?

Comment: The script does not makes sense. `$('#cart_total')` does nothing, `callback` is not defined, `html+` will concatenate the string representation of the `html` method with another string, and the result is not used.